# Is it okay to use a recursive method with SQL in it in order to get a unique 4-character ID?

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a PHP/MySQL e-commerce site that needs 4-character order IDs. Is it okay to use a recursive method like this:

```
private function getOrderId() {
    $chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $num_chars = strlen($chars);
    $id_len = 4;
    $candidate_id = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < $id_len; ++$i) {
        $candidate_id .= $chars[mt_rand(0, $num_chars - 1)];
    }

    // check if $candidate_id exists using MySQL

    //
    if($it_exists) {
        return $this->getOrderId();
    }
    else {
        return $candidate_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does recursion buy you that a normal loop doesn't?

Comment: Consider to use `INSERT IGNORE` instead of checking for existence with `SELECT`. There is still a chance that a cuncurrent user will grab the exactly same ID at (almost) same time.